# Capturar toda ID com preg_match

Tags: php

Tenho duas div

```
<div id"opcao1"></div>

<div id"opcao1a"></div>
```

Estou utilizando esta função para capturar o id

```
function obterID($string) {
    $res = preg_match('~id="([\w]+)"~i', $string, $IDs);
    if ($res){
        return $IDs[1];
    } else {
        return "";
    }      
}
```

Mas recebo apenas a div opcao1, a div opcao1a, não retorna.

Alguém sabe como fazer isto

Comment: Não seria mais fácil você pegar esse ID com jQuery ou JS?

Comment: Tem duas divs onde? De onde tirou essa função? Como está usando a função? Aliás, pra que usar uma função que faz quase a mesma coisa que o `preg_match`, mas retorna um item só? Seria legal [edit] a questão e colocar mais detalhes, pois da forma como está, o contexto fica dependendo muito da imaginação de cada um. Explicando melhor, aumenta a chance de obter uma solução. Se bem que eu acho que simplesmente eliminando a função redundante obterID, já resolve o problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = '
<div id="opcao1"></div>

<div id="opcao1a"></div>
';

$doc = new DOMDocument();

@$doc->loadHTML($str); // Aqui usamos o inibidor de erros `@` para evitar o disparo de erros devido a semântica inválida de algum código html.

$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->getAttribute('id').PHP_EOL.'<br />';
}
```

obs: no código original da pergunta há um erro de sintaxe. Falta o atribuidor `=` nas tags `div`.

Errado: `<div id"opcao1"></div>`.

Correção: `<div id="opcao1"></div>`.